# Java parallel tasks , only executing once

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

This code I have is not executing tasks in parallel, 
it only executes the code in this case once (whatever is in the for loop, but it should be 2) :

```
public class mqDirect {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int parallelism = 2;
        ExecutorService executorService =
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism);
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(parallelism);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                // snip ... do stuff.. 
                semaphore.release();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                semaphore.release();
            }

            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry wont let me post the code, despite trying to format it ..

Comment: https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/833/42751117694_288805b97d_b.jpg

Comment: You can post the code as text, others might be able to edit it into shape.

Comment: Your example creates an `ExectorService` instance that it never uses. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java the main way to make code work in parallel is to create a [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) with a new [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) as a constructor parameter. You then need to [start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) it.

There are many tutorials to help you get this to happen properly.

As your code stands you are merely creating an `ExecutorService` (and not using it), creating a `Semaphore` (which should be done in the `thread` but isn't), performing some process and then shutting down the `Executor`.

BTW: `ShutDownNow` is probably not what you want, you should just use `ShutDown`.

Comment: Re "...create a `Thread` ... You then need to start it or use an `Executor`." IMO, that's confusing. You seem to suggest solving a problem by creating a new `Thread` instance, and then using an `Executor` to do something to the new `Thread`. That makes no sense. You probably meant to suggest using an `Executor` _instead of_ using `Thread`, but I don't think that's how your answer would look to a newbie who is unfamiliar with the _thread pool_ concept.

Answer (score 0):

> This code I have is not executing tasks in parallel, it only executes the code in this case once (whatever is in the for loop, but it should be 2) :

Just because you instantiate an `ExecutorService` instance doesn't mean that things magically run in parallel.  You actually need to *use* that object aside from just shutting it down.

If you want the stuff in the loop to run in the threads in the service then you need to do something like:

```
int parallelism = 2;
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism);
for (int i = 0; i < parallelism; i++) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        // the code you want to be run by the threads in the exector-service
        // ...
    });
}
// once you have submitted all of the jobs, you can shut it down
executorService.shutdown(); 
// you might want to call executorService.awaitTermination(...) here
```

It is important to note that this will run your code in the service but there are no guarantees that it will be run "in parallel".  This depends on your number of processors and the race conditions inherent with threads.  For example, the first task might start up, run, and finish its code *before* the 2nd one starts.  That's the nature of threaded programs which are by design asynchronous.

If, however, you have at least 2 cores, and the code that you submit to be run by the executor-service takes a long time to run then most likely they will be running at the same time at some point.

Lastly, as @OldCurmudgeon points out, you should call `shutdown()` on the service which allows current jobs already submitted to the service to run as opposed to `shutdownNow()` which cancels and queued jobs and also calls `thread.interrupt()` on any running jobs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I found this good tutorial 
http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/threadpoolexecutor

And I have done something like

```
public class mqDirect {
int poolSize = 2;

int maxPoolSize = 2;

long keepAliveTime = 10;

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = null;

final ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(
        5);

public mqDirect()
{
    threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize,
            keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

}

public void runTask(Runnable task)
{

    threadPool.execute(task);

    System.out.println("Task count.." + queue.size());

}

public void shutDown()
{
    threadPool.shutdown();
}





public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
{

    mqDirect mtpe = new mqDirect();
    // start first one
    mtpe.runTask(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("First Task");
                    runMqTests();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // start second one
    /*
     * try{ Thread.sleep(500); }catch(InterruptedException
     * ie){}
     */
    mtpe.runTask(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Second Task");
                    runMqTests();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mtpe.shutDown();

   // runMqTests();

}
```

And it works ! 
But the problem is , this duplicated code ... runMqtests() is the same task, is there a way to specify it to run in parallel without duplicating the code?

The example I based this off is assuming each task is different.